# getting past event for Google Analytics

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, google-analytics

I followed this guide below:

http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started&referringTitle=Overview

It teaches me on google analytics basics. Over at the STANDARD REPORTS I am able to see my **real time screens** and **events** that happened. But it is only **real time**, how can I see **past real time results** ? On the real time view, there is only last 30mins recorded. Is the link teaching me the right way to store on google analytics ? Where can I retrieve the past events?

Check out this image:
http://i62.tinypic.com/dngl05.png

Comment: https://www.google.com/analytics  on the left check under Standard reports -> behavior -> Events

Comment: @DaImTo werid it says There is no data for this view. Check out my updated pictures.

Comment: How long ago did you add the event loging? It can take up to 24 hours to show up on the standard reports

Comment: @DaImTo oh, it takes 24hours ??? Okay i shall wait a bit more. I thought its like real time that shows straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real time reports are just that whats happening on your site right now in real time.  But you may have noticed that there isn't a lot of data there.  This is because it takes time for Google to process and analyse the data that is sent from your site.  That's why it can take up to 24 hours before Google is done processing the data for display in the standard reports.

```
Google Analytics generally updates your reports every 24 hours, so it can take at least
that long for data to appear in your account after you first install the tracking code.
```

That comes directly from Googles help. [Data delay after adding the tracking code](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009219?hl=en)

Personal experience has shown that you can sometimes see it as soon as 4 - 8 hours but that depends a lot I think on the amount of data the site/app sends.  Its probably not something that I would depend on.  Its best to just assume that you can first see today's data tomorrow.

Comment: I had this problem too, takes about a day to appear in the historical view. +1